# How does one generate client and server code manually for Java in gRPC?

Tags: java, grpc, grpc-java

The [official documentation](https://grpc.io/docs/tutorials/basic/java/) states the following with respect to generating client and server code.

> Next we need to generate the gRPC client and server interfaces from
>   our .proto service definition. We do this using the protocol buffer
>   compiler protoc with a special gRPC Java plugin. You need to use the
>   proto3 compiler (which supports both proto2 and proto3 syntax) in
>   order to generate gRPC services.

Unfortunately, it simply suggests that one uses Maven or Gradle to generate the actual client and server stubs.

What is the actual `protoc` command line invocation for this generation?

Answer (score 4):

The [gRPC Java Codegen Plugin for Protobuf Compiler](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/tree/master/compiler) readme file talks about this:

> To compile a proto file and generate Java interfaces out of the
>   service definitions:
>
> ```sh
> $ protoc --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc-java=build/exe/java_plugin/protoc-gen-grpc-java \
>   --grpc-java_out="$OUTPUT_FILE" --proto_path="$DIR_OF_PROTO_FILE" "$PROTO_FILE"
> ```